# Devolver consulta como array - NodeJS

Tags: mysql, nodejs

Tengo esta consulta que hago en mi REST API la cual lista los items de la siguiente forma.

Consulta

```
SELECT `i`.`name`, `i`.`id`, `i`.`img`, `d`.`url`, GROUP_CONCAT(t.name SEPARATOR ', ') as tags FROM `demos` i INNER JOIN `details` d ON `i`.`id` = `d`.`demo_id`  INNER JOIN tags t ON t.demo_id = i.id  GROUP BY `i`.`id` ORDER BY `i`.`id` ASC LIMIT " + req.params.limit
```

Resultado

```js
{
    "name": "unintento",
    "id": "yiouq9",
    "img": "https://xxx.s3.amazonaws.com/demos/1490370081236",
    "url": "http://192.168.0.66:9966/cms/demos",
    "tags": "PHP, Joomla"
  },
```

Basicamente que en lugar de devolverse separado por comas se devuelva como un `ARRAY`.
Cual es la forma de hacer esto?

Comment: Lo que muestras en tu respuesta no es un JSON válido. Tags debe ser un array, no un objeto

Comment: Tambien me sirve un array, como puedo hacerlo?